# Making a search functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku

[so the picture shown is what I have, I want to make a search functionality with the corresponding 4 items on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLBQS.png)

```
const itemListHTML = `
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-b-50">
         <!-- Block2 -->
         <div class="block2">
             <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative block2-labelnew" id="itemLabel">
                 <img alt="IMG-PRODUCT" id="itemImage">
             </div>

             <div class="block2-txt p-t-20">
                 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5" onclick="getItemDetails(event)">
                    <span id="itemId" hidden></span><span id="itemTitle"></span>
                 </a>

                 <span class="block2-price m-text6 p-r-5">
                     $<span id="itemPrice"></span>
                 </span>
             </div>  
         </div>
     </div>
`;
function getitems() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/items",
    success: res => {
      if (res.success == 0) handle_error(res.error);
      else {
        res.data.rows.forEach(row => {
          const $itemList = $(itemListHTML);
          $itemList.find("#itemImage").attr("src", row.picture);
          $itemList.find("#itemId").text(row.item_id);
          $itemList.find("#itemTitle").text(row.title);
          $itemList.find("#itemPrice").text(row.price);
          if (row.sale == true) {
            $itemList
              .find("#itemLabel")
              .removeClass("block2-labelnew")
              .addClass("block2-labelsale");
          }
          $("#item-list").append($itemList);
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

function getItemDetails(event) {
  const itemId = $(event.target)
    .siblings("span")
    .text();
  window.location.href = "/product-detail.html?itemid=" + itemId;
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  getitems();
});
```

This is my product.js file which is able to retrieve the items as shown in the picture.

How do I search using just the title of the product to get my items item display on a new webpage?

```
<!-- search button -->
<div class="search-product pos-relative bo4 of-hidden">
                <input class="s-text7 size6 p-l-23 p-r-50" type="text" name="search-product" placeholder="Search Products...">
                <button class="flex-c-m size5 ab-r-m color2 color0-hov trans-0-4">
                <i class="fs-12 fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>
    <!-- search button end here -->

<!-- Product -->
    <div class="row" id="item-list"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same GET url then filter the array.

In new page try something like this.

```
 itemid=GetQueryStringParams("itemid");
 var selectedRow;
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/items",
    success: res => {
      if (res.success == 0) handle_error(res.error);
      else {
         var rows=res.data.rows;
         selectedRow=rows.filter(function(el) {
          return el["title"]==itemid;
          })
      }
    }
  });
```

**EDIT :**

> ```
> function GetQueryStringParams(sParam) {
>     var sPageURL = window.location.hash.split("?")[1];
>     if (sPageURL == undefined) {
>         return ""
>     }
>     var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split("&");
>     for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
>         var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split("=");
>         if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
>             return sParameterName[1]
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: how will i take the input from the form and compare it to get the results once i click the button